# How to kill a third-party app like Instagram? - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, background-process

I´m trying to kill the background process from the app "instagram" with "killBackgroundProcesses", but it doesn´t work.

My source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String)

How can I use this code properly?

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions?

Comment: yes, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />